# Why is this true: $P(a \setminus b)=P(a) \iff P(b\setminus a)=P(b)$?

Tags: probability

let $a,b$ be events. let $P(a)$ denote probability of event $a$. The slash represents conditional probability.

Why is this true: $P(a \setminus b)=P(a) \iff P(b\setminus a)=P(b)$?

I can prove this by algebraically manipulating the definition of conditional probability, but fail to see intuitively/logically why it is true.

It feels like it could be the case that event $b$ makes $a$ more likely, but event $a$ does not make event $b$ more likely.

Please help me understand this at a conceptual level.

Comment: What kind of objects are $a$ and $b$, and what is the meaning of $P(b\setminus a)$? Is that slash supposed to be division, conditional probability, or set-minus?

Comment: @Michael updated

Comment: So you have events $A, B$ with $P[A]>0, P[B]>0$, and you are asking about $$P[A|B]=P[A] \iff P[B|A]=P[B]$$ Intuitively this is because if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $B$ and $A$ are independent.

Comment: The LHS implies that conditioning on B does not impact A, which means A and B are independent. Since A and B are independent, conditioning on A does not have an impact on B. Similarly logic going from the RHS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "feels like it could be the case" is wrong! If $b$ makes $a$ more likely (that is, $P(A \mid B) > P(A)$), then witnessing $a$ **is** evidence for $b$ (that is, $P(B \mid A) > P(B)$).

For example: if Dutch people are more likely to be taller, and you find out that someone is very tall, then (knowing nothing else) you would be correct to assign more probability to their being Dutch. After all, you found out that they are tall, so that makes them less likely to be Sri Lankan (because Sri Lankan population height averages much lower); that extra probability mass that you've taken away from Sri Lanka has to go somewhere (because your total assignment of probabilities to each outcome must still sum to $1$), and some of the extra will land on the Netherlands.

Answer (score 1):

Fuzzily speaking,

$P(a|b)=P(a)$

$\implies$ knowing that $B$ occurs does not change $A$'s probability

$\implies$ $A$'s probability is the same regardless of whether we know that $B$ occurs

$\implies$ $A$'s probability is useless for inferring $B$'s occurrence

$\implies$ knowing that $A$ occurs does not change $B$'s probability

$\implies P(b|a)=P(b).$

The converse is likewise.

Answer (score 0):

We have two events $A$ and $B$ with $P(A) > 0$ and $P(B) > 0$.

By definition:
$$
P(A | B) = {P(A \cap B) \over P(B)} \ \ \mbox{and} \ \
P(B | A) = {P(A \cap B) \over P(A)} \tag{1}
$$

Note that
$$
P(A | B) = P(A) \iff {P(A \cap B) \over P(B)} = P(A) \iff
P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B) \tag{2}
$$

$$
P(B | A) = P(B)  \iff {P(B \cap A) \over P(A)} = P(B) \iff
P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B) \tag{3}
$$

From (2) and (3), it is immediate that
$$
P(A | B) = P(A) \iff P(B | A) = P(B) \iff A, B \ \mbox{are independent events}
$$

Answer (score 0):

you can write conditional probability if the two events are independent.

$$P(A/B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.$$
and
you can write

$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$
plug this into equation 1

gives  you
$$P(A/B)=P(B).$$

good luck

Answer (score 0):

First think that the only way that $P(A|B)$ equals $P(A)$ is if both the cases in which $A$ occurs and the cases in which $A$ does not occur were reduced in the same proportion when $B$ was applied, so the result of the division is still the same.

In other words, the event $B$ must consist in a fraction of $A$ joined with the same fraction of $¬A$. To illustrate, let's say it takes $\frac{1}{2}$ of each. Then the probability of $A$ given $B$ is:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}|A|}{\frac{1}{2}|A| + \frac{1}{2}|¬A|} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}|A|}{\frac{1}{2}(|A|+|¬A|)} = \frac{|A|}{|\Omega|} = P(A)$$

But that fraction $\frac{1}{2}$ is in fact $P(B)$, because it is taken from both $A$ and $¬A$ that together consist in the sample space.

Now, when we calculate $P(B|A)$, the favorable cases are those renmant from $A$ when intersecting with $B$, that would be $\frac{1}{2}|A|$ in our example, and the total number of cases are $|A|$. Then that probability is $\frac{1}{2}$, so $P(B)$.

This proves the implication. The reciprocal is analogous.